# Do the DSLRKIT PT-08XT triggers work with a Vivitar 283 flash and a Sony NEX 6?

Tags: troubleshooting, off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers

I've just got a couple of Vivitar 283 flashes and a set of [DSLRKIT PT-08XT radio triggers](http://www.dslrkit.com/pt-08xt-hot-shoe-flash-trigger.html). The plan was to have some external flashes which would remote trigger from the NEX 6. The hot-shoe on the NEX 6 is apparently standard so I thought it would just work like on a DSLR.... Has anyone had similar problems with not being able to make the set up work and know a work-around or have I bought a kit that's not compatible?

Comment: Just to be clear -- similar problems to _what_? It's not working at all?

Comment: Yes sorry, my bad.... Yes you're right I can't make the set up work....

Comment: Are you using PC cords at the flash end? (The hot shoe on the receivers won't work with 283s.) And does the test button on the transmitter fire the flashes?

Comment: Hi Stan, I'm not using a PC cord on the flash end but the flash fires when I press the test button on the transmitter so I guess the receivers/transmitter and flashes are all working together ok. It's only when I attached the transmitter to the nex 6 via the hot shoe that it doesn't fire when I take a picture...

Answer (score 1):

Have you measured the voltage that your 283 presents? How old are the 283? I have a late 70s vintage 285, and it presents about 350V across the contacts. That worked great with my Nikon F, but will fry a lot of modern electronics. Your flash claims to work to 250V.

Comment: I'm not contacting the flashes directly to the camera so not chance of frying.... I'm trying to get them to work through the triggers. Think the 283 are about the same age as your 285.. But I've not measured so not 100% about the voltage...

Comment: Good approach. Normal problem solving would be to just use a PC-sync cable and make sure that works. Remove triggers from path. But  you really need a voltage isolator, like http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/245292-REG/Wein_W990560_Safe_Sync_Hot_Shoe_to.html

Comment: @ Pat, Problem is the nex doesn't have a PC port :( which make life harder! stupid Sony.... I will look into the voltage isolators though, it might solve it.... Thanks for your help Pat

Answer (score 0):

You may have fried the triggers--most of these cheap eBay type triggers have a voltage limit of around 300V, and the Vivitar 283s are known to go higher. So, maybe a voltmeter would be worth the investment.

I would also go to the standby advice of check the batteries and the channel settings.

Theoretically, those triggers (which look like they're for Nikon from the pass-through shoe's contact pattern) *should* work.  But if they rely upon a TTL pin signal of some kind, that could be another issue.  It's unlikely that this is the case, since those triggers have separate Tx/Rx units, and I've only see this type of misfunction with the Yongnuo RF-603s (which used a TTL signal to auto switch between Tx/Rx modes, so with non-Canon/Nikon hotshoes, the transmitter unit never went into Tx mode--which is why Yongnuo made an RF-603 II).

I've seen reports that the Yongnuo RF-603ii triggers work on NEX (and Fuji X and micro four-thirds), but the sync voltage limit is still only 300V (still better than the 11V limit on the 602s and 603s).